# Cert manager doesn't get the challenge done

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt, k3s, cert-manager, acme

I'm setting up a k3s cluster for local development.
To be clear, I do not have a public IP address.

At this moment I'm looking for a solution to get the certificate process automated (via cert-manager).
In order to get this to work I've did the following:

- Deployed k3s
- Deployed cert-manager
- Deployed traefik
- Purchased a domain
- Created a cloudflare account and added the domain there
- Created an API token to do the acme challenge (based on https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/cloudflare/)
- Created a simple test website

When a add the test website I get the following error:

> Found no Zones for domain _acme-challenge.. (neither in
> the sub-domain noir in the SLD) please make sure your domain-entries
> in the config are correct and the API is correctly setup with
> Zone.read rights.

I have the following configuration:
**ClusterIssuer**

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    email: my@emailaddress.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudflare:
          email: my@emailaddress.com
          apiKeySecretRef:
            name: cloudflare-api-key-secret
            key: api-key
```

**Test website**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.<mydomain>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name:  nginx-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    - secretName: test.<mydomain>
```

Answer (score 1):

having gone through this myself recently, I've personally using both letsencrypt (for internal only) and cloudflare for external.

For cloudflare see my blog article here:

https://blog.foulkes.cloud/devops/picluster/edge-networking/cloudflare/2023/01/22/using-cloudflare-with-k3s-and-cert-manager.html

For lets encrypt you'll need to use a split horizon dns setup. Which involves using DNS verification against the domain.